# Does Resharper have more rules than SonarLint?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sonarqube, resharper, sonarlint

Jetbrains [brags on their website](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/comparisonMatrix_R2016_3_vs2015.html) that Resharper 2016.3 has over two thousand more rules than Visual Studio 2015. But how does Resharper 2016.3 compare to SonarLint? (a popular plugin for Visual Studio 2015)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ReSharper has more rules. However, the covered cases might not show such big difference than the advertised numbers. For example SonarLint [S2971](http://www.sonarlint.org/visualstudio/rules/index.html#sonarLintVersion=3.0.0&ruleId=S2971) covers many cases. In ReSharper each of these are considered individual rules.